# Perltidy always prints to standard out

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

My [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) always prints to standard out instead of the default `test.pl.tdy`:

```
perltidy test.pl
```

And here is my `.perltidyrc`:

```
-pbp # Start with Perl Best Practices
-w
-l=100   # 100 characters per line
-ce # 'cuddled' elses. elses appear on the same line as last brace
-pt=2 # no parentheses spacing
-pt=2    # High parenthesis tightness
-bt=2    # High brace tightness
-sbt=2   # High square bracket tightness
-bar # opening braces right
-nsbl # open subroutine brace on right
-bbvt=1 # Block Brace Vertical Tightness
-sot # stack opening tokens
-sct # stack closing tokens
-nsfs # no For Loop Semicolon Spaces
-nolq # don't outdent long strings
```

Even if I do:

```
perltidy -b test.pl
```

It will still print to standard out and not go to `test.pl.bak`. The only way I can get it to go to a different file is by doing:

```
perltidy test.pl > test.pl.tdy
```

Is there something in my `.perltidyrc` that could be causing this? I can't seem to find anything to explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says in [Styles section](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html#Styles)

> -pbp, --perl-best-practices
>    -pbp is an abbreviation for the parameters in the book Perl Best Practices by Damian Conway:
>
> ```
> -l=78 -i=4 -ci=4 -st -se -vt=2 -cti=0 -pt=1 -bt=1 -sbt=1 -bbt=1 -nsfs -nolq
> -wbb="% + - * / x != == >= <= =~ !~ < > | & =
>       **= += *= &= <<= &&= -= /= |= >>= ||= //= .= %= ^= x="
> ```
>
> Please note that this parameter set **includes -st and -se flags**, which make perltidy act as a filter on one file only.  These can be **overridden by placing -nst and/or -nse** after the -pbp parameter.

(my emphasis)   The relevant flags are described in [I/O control section](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html#I-O-control).

I don't know why `-pbp` includes the flags to print to standard streams, which imply that there must be only one input file, but there may be a reason; so it may be a good idea to inspect in detail what all those flags under it do.

I find that `-nst` (`--nostandard-ouput`) works even *right* after the `-pbp`, on the same line.