# Why is perltidy going to stdout?

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

I have a bash command, `get-modified-perl-files`, that returns all the Perl files I have modified in my repository. I would like to use perltidy on all of these files.

I created a bash function to do the job:

```sh
tidy() {
    for f in `get-modified-perl-files`
    do
        echo $f
        perltidy -b $f
    done
}
```

According to the help page of perltidy, the -b option should create a backup of my original file and modify it in-place:

> -b      backup original to .bak and modify file in-place

However, when I launch my bash function, no backup is created.  My files are not modified, but the output of perltidy is printed on the standard output. As a consequence, I decided to change my call to perltidy that way:

```sh
\cp $f $f.bak
perltidy $f > $f
```

Now, when I run my command, the backup of my file is correctly done, but the original file is emptied, and the following message is displayed:

> skipping file: file.pl: Zero size

I've found a workaround which gives the result I want, but it seems far-fetched:

```sh
\cp -f $f $f.bak
echo "$(perltidy $f)" > $f
```

Why the -b option doesn't work? Is there a way to do the same job without using this weird redirection?

---

EDIT: Here is my `.perltidyrc` file:

```
--perl-best-practices
--no-standard-error-output
--closing-side-comments
--closing-side-comment-interval=10
--blanks-before-subs
--blanks-before-blocks
--maximum-line-length=130
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default [`perltidy`](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html) does not print the file contents to STDOUT.  To do so requires the `-st` option (or `--standard-output`).  Since you are not using this option on the `perltidy` command line, there is likely a `.perltidyrc` file with `-st` in it that is being used.

To ignore the `.perltidyrc` file, use the `-npro` (`--noprofile`) option:

```
perltidy -npro -b $f
```

Refer to the "Using a *.perltidyrc* command file" section of the man page for your installed version:

```
perldoc perltidy
```

For addition debug information, you can run:

```
perltidy -dpro
perltidy -dop
```

---

Another possibility is that you aliased the `perltidy` command to `perltidy -st`.  You should be able to avoid an alias with:

```
\perltidy -npro -b $f
```

---

Now that you edited your Question to show your `.perltidyrc` file, it looks like the culprit is:

```
--perl-best-practices
```

Either change the rc file, or ignore it as above.

See also [Perltidy always prints to standard out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229423/perltidy-always-prints-to-standard-out)

Answer (score 5):

> `perltidy $f > $f`

This will never do what you want, with any program. When you run a program with `> $f`, that tells the shell that you want the program to run with its stdout connected to `$f`. So before the program is run, the shell opens `$f` for writing, which destroys the contents of the file. Then it connects the handle to stdout in the child, then it runs perltidy, which tries to read `$f` and finds... nothing, because the original contents were already wiped out. Not a recipe for success. This is why perltidy has its own "in-place editing" feature in the first place.

Comment: The `sponge` utility is useful for utilities that don't provide in-place editing. `prog file >file` can be solved using `prog file | sponge file`